# using die function in PHP to stop execution of code but stay on the same page

Tags: php

I have a form where the user can insert an image, it has validation on it and I am using die to stop the execution of the rest of the code.  This works fine but when user clicks submit it takes them to a blank page, instead of the error showing up on the form to allow them to enter information.

Here is some PHP code I am using that is causing this:

```
//If the error number is greater than 0, there's an error.
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
$uploadErr = "An error ocurred when uploading.";
die;

}

//Check if the file type is allowed.
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != "jpg" && $_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != "png" && $_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != "jpeg" && $_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != "gif") { 
$uploadErr = "Unsupported file type, only jpg, png or gif allowed";
die;

}

//check the file size does not exceed the limit
if($_FILES['file_upload']['size'] > 500000){
$uploadErr = "File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.";
die;

}

//Check that the file doesn't already exist (based on name).
if(file_exists('img/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
$uploadErr = "File with that name already exists.";
die;

}

//check file is an actual image
if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
 $uploadErr = "Please ensure you are uploading an image.";
 die;

}
```

Comment: `die($uploadErr);` isntead of `die;`?

Comment: why not implement it using ajax.

Comment: You should really implement some proper error handling instead of just using `die`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the error message, pass `$uploadErr` to `die()`:

```
die($uploadErr);
```

Comment: tried this, it comes up the error but on a blank page. @jeromegamez

Comment: Ah, I thought the issue was just that the page was blank, not showing the error message. If you want to display the error inside the form, you will have to use AJAX or redirect the use back to the page they came from.

Comment: how do i use AJAX to achieve this? @jeromegamez

Comment: Sorry @Jordan, but I think this goes far beyond the scope of this question :)